# iOS how to keep current location center all the time

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, core-location

My map shows current location with blue dot..
Of course, when I move, blue dot moves.. I just want to keep blue dot center of the map all the time, making map's moving instead like Google map navigator..

I searched a lot but couldn't find the way...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your map view delegate, do this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: That's what I was after.. Thanks :)

Comment: @daniel how to move this point to center bottom? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481559/viewforannotation-didnt-moves-the-userlocation

Comment: This function does not give smooth motion.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;`, you'll get smoother panning than using the location manager manually.

In addition note that there is a ready-made button for managing the various tracking states:
`MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to create a new UIView on top of your map's view with a blue dot and only move the map's view.

Comment: There's no need to move the map's view; instead, you change the region displayed on the map. And if you do that correctly there's no need for a separate view for the position indicator.

Comment: Sure, as far as he is using a mapview (and we don't know it yet)