# viewForAnnotation didn't moves the userLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mkuserlocation

I've implemented `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {` method to change the default location of userLocation Annotation. Inside this method I've used:

```
if (annotation==(mapView.userLocation)) {
    MKAnnotationView *myAnotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] init];

    myAnotation.image = self.userPointImage.image; 
    myAnotation.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, 250);

    return myAnotation;
}
else
{
    return nil;
}
```

Which successfully moves the default userLocation annotation to center bottom. But as I'm also using heading so when move my phone it is still rotating the map from center.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *) newHeading {

    [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:true];
}
```

But the userLocation annotation is below. So how to do that?

**UPDATE**
 I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421106/centering-mkmapview-on-spot-n-pixels-below-pin) question and tried applying it. But as I'm using heading so it crashes the app.
In my `didUpdateUserLocation` method I added `[self moveCenterByOffset:CGPointMake(0, 200) from:userLocation.coordinate];` and this method is as follows:

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)moveCenterByOffset:(CGPoint)offset from:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    CGPoint point = [self.mapView convertCoordinate:coordinate toPointToView:self.mapView];
    point.x += offset.x;
    point.y += offset.y;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = [self.mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
    return center;
}
```

and then in my `didUpdateUserLocation` method I updated it as: `MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([self moveCenterByOffset:CGPointMake(0, -250) from:userLocation.coordinate], 800.0f, 200.0f);` and `[mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];` as I'm using heading so animation is set to `NO`. But now as I run the code it starts jerking between center and the new point.

Comment: Try this `[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone];`to avoid the jerking problem

Comment: @ReinierMelian but I want to use heading this is the requirement. As user moves the map moves and follows his direction.

Comment: Let me know if I am wrong, you need track the user movements but change his position to a fake position? this is what you need to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

MKCoordinateRegion region = mapClinicsView.region;

set 'region.center' 
It will helps you to navigate your map center position

make sure 'region.center' and annotation center latitute and longitute is same

Comment: Hey I think I got your point and it can be successful. See the update portion of my question. It's now jerking between two points. It's like it sets the point below and then again animate it to center.